# Boto3 AWS Glue Crawler: how to get last run table changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

In the AWS console, we can see if a crawler run returned with changes in schema for particular tables:

[image]

If I were to click on where it says "3 table changes", I would see the names of the tables that changed in that run.

Using boto3 or the API, how can I do that?

Using [get_crawler_metrics](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue/client/get_crawler_metrics.html) only returns the number of affected tables, not the names of the tables.